# How do you get excel to ignore division by 0 in a sumproduct?

Tags: excel, zero

I have a sum product where I need to divide, so one of the inputs is `1/AL:AL`. The problem is that some of those cells are 0. I have tried `1/if(AL:AL=0,1,AL:AL)` and `iferror(1/AL:AL,1)` but both still return `#DIV/0!`. Here is my actual formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT('Data'!$I:$I,'Data'!$AV:$AV,**1/'Data'!$AL:$AL**)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Data!$I:$I,Data!$AL:$AL*(Data!$AV:$AV<>0)/((Data!$AV:$AV=0)+(Data!$AV:$AV<>0)*Data!$AV:$AV))
```

However, I highly recommended to never use full column references with array formulas or functions that calculate arrays.  Sumproduct is a function that calculates arrays, and using whole column references can be very detrimental to the speed and efficiency of your workbook.  Always try to use as limited a range as possible, for example the adjusted formula might look like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Data!$I$1:$I$10,Data!$AL$1:$AL$10*(Data!$AV$1:$AV$10<>0)/((Data!$AV$1:$AV$10=0)+(Data!$AV$1:$AV$10<>0)*Data!$AV$1:$AV$10))
```

If you are using whole column references in order to pick up new data as it is entered, please consider using [dynamic named ranges](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830287) or [table references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e).

Answer (score 0):

Your formula with `IFERROR(1/AL:AL,1)` should work if you enter it as an array formula, with the cursor in the formula bar, press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Comment: The full formula would be: `{=SUMPRODUCT('Data'!$I:$I,'Data'!$AV:$AV,IFERROR(1/'Data'!$AL:$AL,1))}`